# Azure Functions Runtime v1 EventGrid Subscription create fails

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

What I'm doing wrong or how to make it work?
I'm using Azure Runtime v1 (need to use .NET Framework, not core).

Function code in Visual Studio as follows:

```
// This is the default URL for triggering event grid function in the local environment.
// http://localhost:7071/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName={functionname} 

using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid;
namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models.EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add subscription for that function, regardless if through portal or cli, I'm getting following error:

```
PS Azure:\> az eventgrid event-subscription create -g [<myGroupName>] --topic-name data-generated --name Func1Subs --endpoint "https://[<myFunctionAppName>].azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName=Function1&code=[<code>]"
Argument 'resource_group_name' has been deprecated and will be removed in version '2.1.0'. Use '--source-resource-id' instead.
Argument 'topic_name' has been deprecated and will be removed in version '2.1.0'. Use '--source-resource-id' instead.
The attempt to validate the provided endpoint https://[<myFunctionAppName>].azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig failed. For more details, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation.
```

I tried both system code obtained from GET request on `https://[<myFunctionAppName>].azurewebsites.net/admin/host/systemkeys/eventgridextensionconfig_extension?code=[<master_key>]`, default key and even master key itself - same result.

When using the button on the portal to "Add Event Grid subscription" - I also get this error in Notification box.

When I create a function on portal - creating subscription works fine.
Also when I deploy a .netcore function to 2.x runtime - and use the portal button to create subscription - this works fine as well. But like I said - I want to use runtime 1.x to deploy a .NETFramework function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced this one and some observations here

it works fine if I use default function signature

```
    namespace FunctionApp7
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]JObject eventGridEvent, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info(eventGridEvent.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
        }
    }
}
```

but when I use signature like you have mentioned, I get error in creating event subscription. I also need to add nuget package for following to compile 
Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid 3.0.0

```
    namespace FunctionApp10
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models.EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid

Following signature is not applicable for V1 functions

```
public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models.EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, TraceWriter log)
```

Comment: The need of using the nuget package is written in the doc link you shared. I tried with it, because it wasn't working with JObject before, but maybe I used invalid key or so at that time. According to the docs, it should work both ways, since the validation logic should be handled by runtime, not by function. Nevertheless, I'll give it a try again, maybe with fresh function app and eventgrid topic, if you say it worked for you.

Comment: Ugh, switching back to JObject worked... The note on that page is very confusing then - it implies that you can use EventGridEvent, while in fact you can't. Thanks for rechecking this.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate your EventGridTrigger function for Azure Event Grid subscriber using a Postman, see the following:

Request Url:

```
POST https://{myFuncApp}.azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName={myEventGridTriggerFnc}&code={_masterKey}
```

Header:

```
aeg-event-type: SubscriptionValidation
```

Body:

```
[{
   "id": "123",
   "subject": "abc",
   "eventType": "xxx",
   "eventTime": "2019-01-31T16:17:37.1080645Z",
   "data": {
      "validationCode": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "validationUrl": ""
      },
   "dataVersion": "0",
   "metadataVersion": "1",
   "topic": "xxxx"
}]
```

The successful response will return:

```
{"validationResponse":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Notes:

1. The Request Url can be copied from the portal yourFunction/Integrate, property *Event Grid Subscription URL*
2. In the case of manually creating a Request Url, use the _*master* key from the portal yourFunction/Manage page.
3. For testing a function body, use the header *'aeg-event-type: Notification*'

Comment: I don't want to manually validate function. As documentation says, I should only make in function.json input to be eventtrigger and it should do validation automatically.

Comment: This test can be used to validate an url address of the EventGridTrigger function for subscription handler endpoint. If the test passed, then this url address is valid for subscription webhook endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Postman was returning 404 "cannot find function: 'Function1'. When I changed back input parameter to JObject, I received validation code. Thanks for help.